# long digit reading in sas

Tags: sas

I have a long ID number (say, 12184447992012111111). BY using proc import from csv file that number shortens itself with a addition of 'E' in between the digits (1.2184448E19, with format best12. and informat best32.). Browsing here I got to know the csv format itself shortens it previously so it is nothing to do with SAS. So I tried to copy say about 5 numbers and use datalines statement then also it results same.... It wil be helpful if anyone can suggest which format I need to use. Using best32. format I donot get the original number since most probably it modifies that altered number, which infact gives me 12184447992012111872 which is not my desired number.

Comment: I think you might want to read this in using a FILE and INPUT statements. Post some sample data, if other suggestions don't help, and we can help you manually read in the file..rather than use PROC IMPORT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your ID variable is really an identifier rather than a "real" number, you need to read it in as a character string.  The value you show as an example is too large to be represented as an integer, so since SAS stores all numerics as floating point, you are losing "precision".

Since you mention using PROC IMPORT, copy the SAS program it generates and change the FORMAT and INFORMAT specifications from "21." and "best32." to "$32." (or whatever value matched your data.

Best of course would be if you had SAS Access to PC File formats, in which case you cound format the column as "text" in Excel and let SAS read it directly.

Comment: thank you... it solves the problem... I have broken that long number into 4 parts then converterd all of them yo sring and then using 'cat' i have joined them... and voila!! :) :) thanks a lot @Bob

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the csv changing the value (they are just plain text files) - unless you are saving an excel spreadsheet as a csv file. If you are using excel just set the column to number format, no decimal places.

It might be easier to treat the column as text when importing it to SAS - unless you need to perform mathematical operations on it! If you really need to keep it as a number the format 32. should force it to be a 32 digit number - best is fairly sensibly changing it into scientific notation (though I suspect the data is there in the background and just displayed unhelpfully).

Comment: 12184447992012111111
12184447992012111111
12184447992012111111
12184447992012111121
12184447992012111122
12184447992012111122
12184447992012111122
12184447992012111122
12184447992012111131
12184447992012111131
12184447992012111131
12184447992012111211
12184447992012111211

^^this is what i have initially in excel. I want to import this numbers exactly in sas. since I want to use proc means and want to catogories my study wrt these IDs. like first 3 are of same kind so corresponding to these 3 rows i want to calculate the mean of a different study variable likewise for the next group and so.

Comment: 1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19
1.21844E+19

^^after saving excel as csv format i got my id s are like this in scientific notation. thus importing this file in sas gives me the same scientific notaton. while putting id s separetely through datalines in sas i get the same outcome.
@syntheticbrain

Answer (score 0):

There is a SAS informat for reading exponential notation - Ew.d where w is the width and d the number of decimal places. In your case, it probably won't help because you will "lose" the complete number - and the value stored in case you read with this informat will be 1.2184448 * (10^19). The only way in your case is to ensure that the program which produces the CSV file outputs it in the right way. If you are creating the data from an Excel worksheet, then format the number in the Excel worksheet to display all the digits correctly.